# MATLAB - minmax() function

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, minimum, minmax

I have downloaded a code which involves a minmax() function, the backbone of the code is shown below:

```
A = [13 5; 
    13, 13; 
    23, 26];

B = [13, 6; 
    13. 6; 
    5, 26];

C = [A;B];
Datad = minmax(C');

G = 178*Datad(1,1)/174*Datad(1,2)
```

and when I run the code, an error message appeared:

> *Undefined function or method 'minmax' for input arguments of type
>   'double'.*

so I went onto google, and this simple code should work:

```
  x=1:10;
   m=minmax(x)

m =

 1    10
```

BUT it did not work and the same error message appeared.

Since I do not think minmax is going to work, my question here is :

Are there any other ways to replace *minmax*? I know there is a *min* and *max* function which could do the job. But I am not sure how would the original *minmax* function work for matrices, since I would need to get it right to be able to get G.

minmax function is defined as: [Here](http://chronux.org/downloads/chronux/chronux/documentation/chronux_2_00/spikesort/utility/datatools/minmax.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `which minmax` to find out where it is located. If you get error `'minmax' not found.`, then you do not have it in you search path.

`which minmax` gives me `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/toolbox/nnet/nnet/nndatafun/minmax.m` (Linux version), so it seems to me that the function `minmax` is in Neural Network Toolbox. So maybe you haven't installed Neural Network Toolbox.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I remember I unticked the box during installation thinking I dont need it!!!! I just downloaded its m-file. now its working! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your code and then you don't need a separate file.

```
minmax = @(x) [min(x(:)) max(x(:))];
```

Note that it does not support `[Y,I] = minmax(X)` syntax mentioned in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since R2017a `bounds` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that matlab can't find the function. There are two likely culprits here.

1) The file is not named `minmax.m`: matlab looks for functions by the file name. In this case, rename the file.
2) The directory in which `minmax.m` is located is not on the matlab `path`. In this case, either add that directory to the path, or move the file to a directory that is on the path (or into the current directory).